# Can i use return statement in jsp?

Tags: jsp, jstl

Can I use  "return" keyword as below with the JSP? I searched for this keyword in JSP documentation and JSTL documentation but was not able to find. Also when I use the keywords true or false with JSP it turns to a different colour . But for return it does not change colour. So is it correct to use return? Please find below my JSP  code.

```
.jsp:

<c:choose>

<c:when test="${(a == 0) && (b == 8) }"> 
return;
</c:when> 

<c:otherwise> 
 ........
 </c:otherwise>
 </c:choose>
```

Comment: If you're using scriptlets and add a `return;` statement  then you will have a bad time. If you're trying to use `return` from your JSL/EL code, I must ask **why** would you want it.

Answer (score 1):

As it appears in your code, `return;` is simply plain text which will be displayed on the webpage.

I don't know what you want to accomplish, but if you really want to call return:

```
<% return; %>
```

Comment: Right, the JSP page just compiles to a function:
 public void _jspService(final javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, final javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) {
}
so, you can do as @Ray Stojonic suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this construction instead of yours.

```
<c:if test="${(a != 0) || (b != 8) }"> 
... code here ...
</c:if>
```

or

```
<c:if test="${!(a == 0 && b == 8)}"> 
... code here ...
</c:if>
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer.

Comment: It simplifiers your checking.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza first answer fixed.

Comment: How's this related to the fact of using `return` (note: main theme in OP's question).

Comment: Above solution is better alternative.

Comment: Could you at least explain why?

Comment: No sense to write empty statement e.g. if (a==0) {return;} else {//do smth} when you can write if (a!=0) {// do something}. And this is jstl but not a function.

Comment: Maybe this is a code sample and there could be more conditions in the `<c:when>`...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JSTL, then there is no `c:return` tag. Instead, just leave that particular `c:when` statement empty or test for the cases you need to handle.

To answer the second part of your question regarding the true and false keywords, please post an example. You IDE does the syntax highlighting, but an example may help someone explain why.